# Do conditional loop

Tags: vba

I am working on a column of data which is changing as it goes downward. When the value of the cell below changes, my code should do some command; if it does not change then it should do nothing.

My codes run as follows

```vb
For y = 51 To 60

  if ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("ax" & y).Value = _
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("ax" & y - 1).Value then

    With .document
      .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCluster").Focus
      .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCluster").selectedIndex = _
                    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("ax" & y).Value
      .getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlCluster").FireEvent "onchange"

      Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
    end with
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having?

Comment: Your code is missing `End If` as well as `Next y`. Not sure if that is the issue you are dealing with?

Comment: If the cell value in the  column of the excel sheet does not change when going downward then the code do nothing . In other words the value that has already been selected in the ajax element of web form do not change. However when the cell value in the column of the excel sheet change the above code should change the ajax element of the web form  according to the cell value.

Comment: I am very new to programming so it could be the issue.

Comment: What works/doesn't work? Do you get error messages - if Yes what are they and on which line?  It's not really clear exactly what you're doing in this process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this implemented in your code could work:

```
Function 123abc() 

Dim i, j as string

i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("ax" & y - 1).Value
j = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet3").Range("ax" & y ).Value)

IF i <> j THEN

   'Do something

End if

End function
```

For instance at cell AX where y is 53:

```
If    AX52 <> AX53 THEN    'true
           'something will happen
End if
```